# Firestore, How to check for duplicate names in dart?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to find a document named the nickname.
I thought the where function find a doc I want. But I don't think that's it.
How to check for duplicate names?
If there is any other better way than the firestore, you can recommend it.

```
checkNicknameOverlap(String nickname) async {
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('nickname')
    .where(nickname, isEqualTo: true)
    .get()
    .then((res) {
      print('found or not');
    });
  }
```

--------update-----------

It's my structure.
[image]

Comment: Please share your Database Structure in order to help you with the query

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the response from firebase you will have a list of string. To remove duplicate from that list you can try this

```dart
var uniqueName = nickNameList.toSet().toList();
```